# Database Design for a system that has Facebook like groups

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I'm creating a system that has Groups. These can be thought of like Facebook Groups. Users can create new groups. Currently I have the following types of groups:

- City Group - Groups based on a certain city. For example "London Buy and Sell Group"
- School Group - Groups based on schools. For example "London University Study Group"
- Interest Group - Groups that are not tied to a place. For example "Over 50's Knitting Group"

In the future more group types will be added. Each group can have different types of options, but all groups have the same basic data:

- An ID
- A creator ID
- A name
- An option description

I'm struggling on putting together a database design for this. My initial thought was to create different tables for the different groups.

For example have a single table called `group`. This table has an `id`, `creator id`, `name`, `description`, `member count`, `timestamps`.

Then have other tables to represent the other groups, and link them to `group`. So I have a `city_group` table that contains and `id`, `group_id`, `city_id`. And the same for the other group types.

The only problem I have with this is `interest_group` doesn't have any extra data that a normal `group`. But for the purpose of being able to query only Interest Groups I thought it might make sense to create an `interest_group` table. It would only have the following columns: `id`, `group_id`, `timestamps` ... which seems a bit wasteful to have a table just for this purpose.

Here's a diagram to make things easier:
[image]

Are there any issues with my solution, or any better ways to solve this design problem?

Comment: Do you have some predefined types of groups? What happens if a user creates a new group? Will it be an interest group? Or you are the only one that can add groups later on?

Comment: The groups created by users will be `city group` and `interest group`. Only admins can create `school groups`. In the future there will be other types of groups such as `sports group` that represents sports teams etc.

Comment: Interesting question you've got here. What about the members that are in these groups? Will there be like a users table and a linking table between users and groups?

Comment: @RaulCuth yes there will be a table `user_group` that links a `user_id` with a `group_id`.

Comment: The thing that bothers me with this design is that, if you look at a group from Group table, you don't know exactly which group type table matches it.

Comment: @RaulCuth yes I agree. I've spent a good while thinking about an alternative model for this problem and this is all I could think of.  I could add a row that stores the type of group, but that type couldn't really be used for any purpose other than visually identifying the group type, or querying a specific group type. Another problem I thought about is as more group types are added it becomes tricky to query multiple tables to display a list of relevant groups to the user.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130518/discussion-between-raul-cuth-and-bughunteruk).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've got an idea, which is a workaround basically: have another table like: group_type in which you have id(the PK) and then you have tablename (the full table name of the type).

Then, you should have a FK from your Group table linking to this group_type table.

```
id    tablename
--------------------
1     School Group
2     Interest Group
```

After all this is done, you could build your queries based on the values from this table, as an example:

`JOIN (SELECT tablename FROM group_type WHERE id=group.group_type_id) ON ..`